# Finding the optimum value of $x$ from the following term

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization, logarithms

\begin{equation}
 \ln\left(\frac{m}{m-x}\right) =  \frac{z-x}{m-x} \, . 
 \end{equation}

Can I use the Lambert W-function to find the optimum value of $x$ and how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the optimum value of $x$? The one which is closest to solving the equation?

Comment: I have $x=m-{m \over e}e^{W\left(e{m-z \over m} \right)}$

Comment: On the other hand, $\ln\left(\dfrac{m}{m-x}\right) -  \dfrac{z-x}{m-x}$ has zero derivative when $x=2m-z$, at least if you have  $\dfrac{m}{z-m} >0$

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. Really appreciate your help. @Henry this is I think why it does not give me the correct answer. It seems that it needs to have a specific assumption in order to give the correct optimum value of $x$. Regards